# How to import CSV containing currency/numbers with commas and $ signs as numeric instead of text on MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I'm using the "Table Data Import Wizard" option by right clicking on the Schema to import CSV files.

My CSV files, however, contain currency characters, such as dollar signs and commas (e.g. $1,025.57). When I import the CSV and change the field type to INT or DOUBLE, MySQL fails to load the data. The only way I can get it to display is if I import those columns as TEXT. Obviously, I don't want it as text. Is there a way to have MySQL Workbench recognize these fields as INT or DOUBLE or as a numeric instead of TEXT?

I'd like to avoid manually opening the CSV and manually formatting it as it involve more work.

Here's the raw data copy and pasted on here:

```
Brand   tag1    tag2    tagID   taggroup    media_type  date    direct_revenue  total_views total_visitors
Jim's Fish Shop Seafood Bait    JFS12481    Fish Bait   Search  1/1/2016    $1.34   250 15
Jim's Fish Shop Seafood Bait    JFS12482    Fish Bait   Search  1/2/2016    $7.87   1,087   67
Jim's Fish Shop Seafood Bait    JFS12483    Fish Bait   Search  1/3/2016    $0.22   2,582   123
Jim's Fish Shop Seafood Bait    JFS12484    Fish Bait   Search  1/4/2016    $2.01   2,126   122
Jim's Fish Shop Seafood Bait    JFS12485    Fish Bait   Search  1/5/2016    $2.58   3,349   223
```

Original picture (from who knows what sort of thing):
[image]

Comment: Does this work?

Edit: Guess not. Um, how would i add it in comments? Sorry, I'm new to the forums.

Comment: But that said, definitely (in my book, if you can) do it the way Sasha did. It is cool to build up those routines/snippets for the custom imports (versus clicking on tools the slow way. In that strategy of code, it is automated. The real test is how it works with a bunch of columns that may interfere with each other.

Comment: I inserted a picture...haha I'm sorry, I don't know how to add a table.

Thank you Sasha. I'll look into this function. I'm relatively new to using MySQL and am still learning the in's and out's.

Comment: Just cut and paste the text I will format it. Pictures are barely of any use. In general, very annoying on the stack. Because people cut and paste your text to make their answer. So a picture is like a waste of time.

Comment: Sure, I just added the raw data onto my original post and included the column headers. Obviously I replaced the names of stuff, but that's basically what the data is like.

Comment: Are you saying you had that in a spreadsheet that you were able to export? Or are you saying you got a raw feed like the text with space separators and all goofy like that? The reason is is that it impacts the coder, and if it is the former, you can greatly ease the work by exporting with the easier format to begin with.

Comment: I had the data in a spreadsheet that I exported from a data source. I was hoping there was a way to just download the data and import it as a spreadsheet into MySQL. What I wanted to avoid was opening the spreadsheet and formatting the spreadsheet. I thought there might've been a simple and easier workaround to manually formatting it on Excel especially if I'm often uploading this same format of data onto MySQL.

Comment: I understand the misery of it. Let's say you have `file101.xlsx` file. Let's say you get a new one with a different name or you name it, one new one per day or whatever. In a folder underneath that folder, have a csv folder. And save in CSV format `file101.csv` or `.txt` ... but save it with double quotes surrounding the data, and comma separated, and numeric format for the dollar amounts. Then it is bonehead simple to bring that data in (like, Sasha does not need to do his trick).

Comment: It is a whole other issue if someone emails you a horrible format, and you have zero chance of saying "hey, let's change the format please" ... For instance, you receive a file transmission from Mars. But in your case, you control it, so make it easy on the data ingest part of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the help of LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE (the server and the client will need to be configured accordingly to support it, another option is to put the file on the server to avoid LOCAL). Tested example:

```
/tmp/test.csv

$1,035.34
$3,506.45

create table t1(amount double);
load data local infile '/tmp/test.csv' into table t1 (@m) 
set amount=replace(replace(@m,'$',''),',','');

select * from t1;
+---------+
| amount  |
+---------+
| 1035.34 |
| 3506.45 |
+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried three things in order to import the data for the currency column.

1) Remove all the decimals and currency symbol from that column.

2) Use encoding cp1250(windows-1250) instead of utf-8.

3) Try to keep the column name as short as possible. I was getting error when my column name was MinimumFaceAmount to AMOUNT and it worked.

With the three above things I was able to import 18k rows in a single shot. Hope it works for you guys.